# XML file "This page can't be displayed" in System32

Tags: c#, xml

I have made a Windows service that uses relative paths.

My windows Service opens a XML document, writes in it, and then saves it and it is in a loop.

When I forced a path to my xml file outside the System32 folder my service can have access to the xml document. However when I use relative paths, because I created a windows service the relative paths is in Windows/System32... So when I put my xml file in Windows/System32 it gives me the "This page can't be displayed' error.

I don't want to be forcing a path to the xml file every single time in my windows Service.

Thanks

Comment: The System32 folder is for *system* files. If you do not work for Microsoft, you have no business placing items in that folder.

Comment: Please describe completely what you are doing and post some code. What says "This page can't be displayed"?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Yeah, don't use relative paths. Or put anything in the system32/syswow64 folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was quite simple.. I had to add the xml file to SysWow64 .

the exact answer actualy is this : The problem is with the system32 folder being the 64 version and the SysWoW64 folder being the 32 bit version.  When you try to open a file with a 32 bit application from the system32 folder, it gets redirected to the SysWow64 folder.  When you get the above error message, the file does not exist in the SysWOW64 folder.  To show this in action try opening the iexplore64, then opening the file.  Try the same thing with the 32 bit version of iexplore.
Copying the .xml files into the SYSWow64 directory should resolve your issue.

I did not think of this though.. I found the answer here : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/xml-file-located-in-system32-folder-is-not/ae6db3af-ddaa-4e5e-ab63-0515cfe8ca57?page=2